# How to addEventListener to stripe elements?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, stripe-payments, checkout

I have been trying to addEventListener to the close button in stripe checkout form(the default one) but it always gives me "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null".
This is the code:

```
<script>
    var pay = document.querySelector(".Header-navClose");
    var pay2 = document.querySelector(".close");
    var modal = document.querySelector(".ReactModal__Content")
    pay.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        pay.style.display="none";
        modal.style.display = "block";
    })
   
</script>
```

And by the way, I'm using **v2** version of stripe checkout.js

Comment: You can't. The whole point of Stripe elements is that they're in an iframe that your code can't access.

Comment: If that was possible, people would find out how to swipe card numbers whilst people think that stripe is a good and secure way to pay.

Answer (score 2):

When you embed a 3rd-party iframe on your site, that site can't change your site's styling and you can't change theirs. In this case, Stripe controls the iframe contents and you control the broader page that it is embedded on.

For more a more customizable checkout experience look into Stripe.js and Stripe Elements: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js

Comment: okay so can I just add a "cancel" button below the "Pay" button and then access it?

Comment: You can add a close/cancel button that is outside of the iframe which hides/removes the iframe from view or redirects the iframe or the whole page to somewhere else depending on your needs. If the button is outside of the iframe, then addEventListener will work on it.